# What does this snippet of C# code do?

Tags: c#

What does result.IsVisible equal?

```
    if(a==b)
        result.IsVisible = obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y'
            && obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false;
```

Comment: Depends on the values of obj1.status.abc_REPORT and obj1.AnotherValue

Comment: I had the strong urge to say 'true or false'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on the values of `obj1.status.abc_Report` and `obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean()` (and it all depends on whether a==b or not).

I'm not quite sure of what the real question is here - which bit is confusing you?

One bit which *may* be confusing you is the shortcircuiting && operator (and possibly the lack of bracing!)

The && operator will *only* evaluate its right hand side if the left hand side evaluates to `true`: and the overall result of the expression is `true` if and only if *both* sides evaluates to `true`. (I'm assuming no strange user-defined conversions here.)

So another way of writing it would be:

```
if (a == b)
{
    bool visibility = false;
    if (obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y')
    {
        if (obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false)
        {
            visibility = true;
        }
    }
    result.IsVisible = visibility;
}
```

Note that a condition comparing Booleans, like this:

```
obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false
```

would usually be written like this:

```
!obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean()
```

(Note the exclamation mark at the start - the logical "not" operator.)

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't understand that the comparisons eval to a bool value on the line that toggles IsVisible

Comment: Thanks, yes, I was getting confused by the && operator, for me this is an example of just because you can write something on one line doesnt mean you should do... what do you think?

Comment: Write code as if the next person to read it is a psychotic killer that knows where you live.

Comment: @Paul: I think that with braces, it would be fine. The && operator is a pretty common one - I'd expect most C# developers to find that version simpler to understand than my expansion of it into nested if blocks.

Comment: Yes && and lack of brackets, I think if it was this 
result.IsVisible = (obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y') && (!obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean()); 
it would have made more sense in first read through

Answer (score 5):

The same as this, in many less lines:

```
if (a==b) {
    if (obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y') {
         if (obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false) {
             result.IsVisible = true;
         }
         else {
             result.IsVisible = false;
         }
    }
    else {
        result.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice refactoring - much clearer than original code
I think you meant to write if (a == b) instead of if (a=b)

Comment: really nice @John. that is why writing  properly structured and easily understandable code is so important.

Comment: Skeet's example below (and I'm sure soon to be above this one) is better because it's shorter. This is just more explicitly laid out.

Comment: Also please note, I do not write code like this nor endorse the use of this example. :)

Comment: The reason I prefer my expansion is because it matches what the compiler does more closely - the compiler effectively uses a temporary variable to work out the value of the RHS and uses a single assignment to IsVisible. Your version mixes the concept of "what we're doing with the result" in with the code of "how the result is found." Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

If a is equal to b:

result will be visible only if:

object1's status's abc_report is Yes(Y = Yes most probably)  AND object1's other value cannot be converted to a Boolean

Comment: @Aamir, I thing the false return from ToBoolean() would be the actual value, not an error indication that the conversion to boolean failed.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. Can't say much without looking at obj1's othervalue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess result.IsVisible is a boolean

It will be true if the following conditions are true:
obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y'
and
obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false

Also, a == b must be true to enter the initial if

Answer (score 0):

lets go line by line:

```
  if(a==b)
```

obvious if value of a equals value of b the execute following line

```
 result.IsVisible = obj1.status.abc_REPORT == 'Y'
        && obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() == false;
```

result is some object (maybe winforms controls etc) which has a property IsVisible set it to true if obj1.status.abc_REPORT is equal to 'Y' and also obj1.AnotherValue.ToBoolean() is equal to false;